# Can an application absorb a mouse click (even when it's not in focus)?

Tags: c++, operating-system, mouseevent, mouse, sfml

I'm using [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/index.php)  to detect mouse clicks.
A basic wrapper to detect where clicks occur, may look like this:

```
sf::Vector2i Block_Until_Mouse_Click(){

    static bool pressed=false;
    sf::Vector2i position;
    while (true){

      if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left))
      {
          if (!pressed){
            position = sf::Mouse::getPosition();
            pressed=true;
            break;
          }
      }
      else{
        pressed = false;
      }   
    }

    return position;
}
```

This allows the printing of coordinates, each time the mouse has been clicked:

```
while (true){
  auto position = Block_Until_Mouse_Click();
  std::cout << position.x << " " << position.y << '\n';
}
```

**Is it possible for the application to absorb these mouse clicks,

without the click having any affect?**

For example, if I had a paint program open, and this "mouse click absorb" program minimized, would it be possible to click on the canvas without being able to draw anything, but still have the coordinates recorded by the "mouse click absorb" program?

---

I'm not sure if this requires operating system changes, changes to the device/driver, or whether it could be achieved through code.  Are there usual software implementations that provide this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for the application to absorb these mouse clicks,
>   without the click having any affect?

With SFML, no. Using OS features, maybe, depending on the OS.

On OS X, there's a screen capture program called Grab that is able to do that. How? Apple hasn't published the software source code (AFAIK) so I can't tell.

I'm not familiar enough with Windows and Linux to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

SFML internally uses operating system handles for their real-time events if I am not mistaken. To be able to achieve what you want you would have to interfere with the other process in code. That work SFML will not do for you since the getter for mouse position of the operating system knows nothing of any other processes living in memory.

A quote from the SFML docs:

> sf::Mouse provides an interface to the state of the mouse.
>
> It only contains static functions (a single mouse is assumed), so it's not meant to be instantiated.
>
> This class allows users to query the mouse state at any time and directly, without having to deal with a window and its events. Compared to the MouseMoved, MouseButtonPressed and MouseButtonReleased events, sf::Mouse can retrieve the state of the cursor and the buttons at any time (you don't need to store and update a boolean on your side in order to know if a button is pressed or released), and you always get the real state of the mouse, even if it is moved, pressed or released when your window is out of focus and no event is triggered.
>
> The setPosition and getPosition functions can be used to change or retrieve the current position of the mouse pointer. There are two versions: one that operates in global coordinates (relative to the desktop) and one that operates in window coordinates (relative to a specific window).

Check the following link: http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.3.2/classsf_1_1Mouse.php#details

So using this mouse API will not block anything in the operating system, it will just interact directly with the mouse.